# Why when I submit a form in wordpress it loads a 404 page though URL is correct

Tags: theme-development, forms, 404-error

I am just creating a simple contact form, but I notice that it seems to post to an invalid page. The url in the browser is correct but the title of the page is "Page not found"

on the top of the page

```
$emailed = false;
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    wp_mail('example@example.com', $_POST['subject'], $_POST['content']);
    $emailed = true;
}
```

below ... the HTML:

```
<form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="post" id="contactform">
    <div class="formelem">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="formelem">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="required email" />
    </div>
    <div class="formelem">
        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <input type="text" name="subject" class="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="formelem">
        <label for="content">Content</label>
        <textarea name="content" cols="30" rows="10" class="required"></textarea>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit Message" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: What URL is your page located?

Comment: The same issue appears if you use WooCommerce Subscriptions and you have input field, named "subscriptions". It took me quite a long time to figure out what's going on and I managed to fix it thanks to this post. I hope that someone using WooCommerce Subscriptions and have a similar issue finds that helpful!

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I could be wrong, but I vaguely remember that: name, email get hijacked by WordPress to do post comments, if you renamed the form elements to be contact-name and contact-email, do you get the same issue?

Comment: Yea it's the name field, namespace it like jm_name instead :)

Comment: Thanks Tom! WP was indeed hijacking the form. That's strange.

Comment: This is also true for AngularJS, in case that helps. ;)

Comment: I faced this issue, this answer directed me to right path. I had no field with name or email, but one of input name was equal to custom post type (cpt) so it was triggering the wp query and 404. So i changed the field name to make it different than cpt, and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Horrible, when using the input field name email not able to insert data.
Thanks Helped me

Comment: Thanks! I had the same issue when using the name `s` for free text search.

Comment: Thank you for this - saved me after hours of debug

Answer (score 9):

It is no only `name`  or `email` problem, as Tom wrote. I had problem even with input field with name attribute same as one of my Custom Post Types. For example:

```
...
<input type="text" name="movie">
...
```

And when having registered CPT "movie" somewhere else, your form submitting will end with 404 error.

Conclusion: Don't use `name`, `email` and `any registered custom post type handle` as input name attribute value in your forms.

Comment: Well, I tried to answer original question with more accurate information. Ehm, probably... :-) Adding a little edit.

Comment: Also, custom taxonomy names are not allowed as input names

Comment: Yes, there is a big list. You can find help from here: https://www.infinitypp.com/wordpress/easily-fix-wordpress-post-request-wont-return-return-404-form-submission/

Answer (score 4):

Try to change `name="email"` to something like `name="my_theme_email"`, do the same with all your field it sounds like some name are reserved with WordPress when sending form data. I got the the same problem and I fixed it like that.

Answer (score 0):

It works to me, just changed your

```
input type name, email, subject, and content to any name as names, emails, subjects, contents.
```

It will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can not use year as the name of the field.

Comment: Which field? Are you passing the year field as a query string parameter or as a field in a posted form? I'd be surprised if this was a general problem.

Comment: Field in a posted form.

`<input type="text" name="year"/>`